# Conforming to a protocol and also having a property with the type of the protocol in the same struct

Tags: swift, protocols, decodable

I have the following struct:

```
struct ImageSlider: CodableComponent {
    let slides: [CodableComponent]?
}
```

which conforms to `CodableComponent`

```
protocol Component {

}

typealias CodableComponent = Component & Decodable
```

But I get the following error:

```
Type 'ImageSlider' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'
```

As soon as I remove the conformance to CodableComponent in ImageSlider, like the following:

```
struct ImageSlider {
    let slides: [CodableComponent]?
}
```

The error is gone.

I'm not sure what exactly is happening here, why I cannot conform to a protocol and also have a property of the same type?

Would be appreciated if someone could shed some light on this case.

Comment: You need to implement `init(from:)`, which is a requirement of `Decodable`. It doesn't get synthesised here because `Component & Decodable` is not `Decodable`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself

Comment: I'm guessing there are only a limited number of `CodableComponent`s that can be in `slides`? Check if you can decode each of them in `init(from:)`.

Comment: Thank Sweeper. The error is gone now. I also found another way to get around it, by using "existential any" in Swift 5.6.

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement Decodable protocol, for example:

```
struct ImageSlider: CodableComponent {
    let slides: [CodableComponent]?
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        // decode values here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I found out that there are 2 ways to address this issue. The first one is using `init(from:)` as you can see in the comments and other answers. The other one is by using "**existential any**" in Swift 5.6

```
struct ImageSlider: any CodableComponent {
    let slides: [any CodableComponent]
}
```